# Custom pin point on Map api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-plus

In my app I implemented the map fragment inside a fragment. I would like to show pins on the map. I know the simple way of [putting the marker on the map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker) is easy.

However in my app I have to save all their information I have to use,two different pins , for example for girls the icon would be pink and for boys the pin would be blue.

Now I want to put some other information for example the id, name and status, age, game, latitude and longitude and so on. I do not want to show all of this information when user click the pins. I want to show the information in a new activity which would get open user click.

Please help me, how can I share the information of each marker completely and then, when the user clicks the marker the new activity should open and show related information. I have searched many tutorials on this topic prior to posting my question.

Answer (score 0):

This should be useful http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/

It has:

Marker clustering — handles the display of a large number of points

Heat maps — display a large number of points as a heat map

IconGenerator — display text on your Markers (see screenshot)

Comment: I know this link , but can you tell me how to achieve this , should I make my model class and generate the getter and setter of the fields which i want to save against each pin ?

Comment: you should follow the demo https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/tree/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo

Comment: is there any easy tutorial ?

Comment: or can I run this demo that you shared here ?

Comment: yes you should clone the project and run the demo so that you can extract needed informations

Comment: I tried and its run perfectly but still I do not understand how can I save my pins information as eaach pin should be recognized as seprate entity , so that if particular pin is selected , I should show its information in new window